# Printing String on a picture in Java

Tags: java

I want to write a string on an existing picture in java. The pic is of .jpg format. I have used the below code, the only problem is that the final image has a red shade on it..something like the image lost its true color and is light red. Please help me to rectify this problem.

```
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("pic1.jpg"));
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 96);
    g2d.setFont(font);
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.drawString(text, 100, 250);
    g2d.dispose();

    File file = new File("newimage.jpg");

    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", file);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use INT_RGB instead of INT_ARGB and you'll be fine:

```
  BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write code like this. There is no need to use BufferedImage class to get image graphic object. This just will do what you want.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("pic1.jpg"));
int width = img.getWidth();
int height = img.getHeight();
Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 96);

g.setFont(font);
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.drawString(text, 100, 250);
g.dispose();

File file = new File("newimage.jpg");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", file);
```